# How to edit a file using Azure DevOps REST API without passing the file version

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to edit a file's last version on TFS using the example shown over here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

But this request demands the file's version to be edited.

Is there a way to edit a file's last version without passing the actual file version?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to edit a file's last version without passing the actual file version?

Based on my test, the version field is required.

So When you use the Rest API to edit a file from TFVC repo, you need to input the latest version.

But you could use the Rest API:[Changesets - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to get the latest version number

Here is a PowerShell Script example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/{Project Name}/_apis/tfvc/changesets?$orderby=id des&api-version=5.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

$latestversion = $response.value.changesetId[0]

echo $latestversion

$url2="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/_apis/tfvc/changesets?api-version=5.0"
   
$body = "{
    `"changes`": [
     {
      `"item`": {
        `"version`": `"$latestversion`",
        `"path`": `"$/TFVCTEST/test.txt`",
        `"contentMetadata`": {
          `"encoding`": 1200,
          `"contentType`": `"text/plain`"
        }
      },
      `"changeType`": `"edit`",
      `"newContent`": {
        `"content`": `"Initial coassdntentssss sas of 4/9/2019 11:21:13 PM\nEdited contents`"
      }
    }
  ],
  `"comment`": `"(sample) Editing the file via API`"
      }"

$response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json
```

**Explanation:**

The first URL is used to get all changestIDs, the results  are sorted in descending order by default. So you only need to take the first value that is the latest value.

Then you could set `the latest value` as `version` in the request body of second Rest API to edit the files.

By the way, considering that you are using TFS, you may need to change the url to the following:

[Changesets - Get Changesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get%20changesets?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)

[Changesets - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)